# How to hide folder names from url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

From the URL to

http://test.com/mycoderprofile/docroot/blogs

http://test.com/mycoderprofile/docroot/value/103

to

http://test.com/blogs

http://test.com/value/103

i have tried this but no luck?

```
    # .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?test.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mycoderprofile/
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mycoderprofile/docrrot/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?test.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mycoderprofile/docroot/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the main configuration, you may just set the [document root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) properly, e.g.

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/mycoderprofile/docroot
```

---

If this is not possible for some reason, the second rule should be sufficient already

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mycoderprofile/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mycoderprofile/docroot/$1 [L]
```

The reason why it does not work, may be the missing [`L|last`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag.

Without this flag, Apache goes on to the following rules and might modify the request further.

Another reason might be, that the resources are created dynamically. This would need further rules, depending on the CMS/framework used.